# Android widget for user info page and circle shape user icon

Tags: android, user-interface, android-widget, material-design, userinfo

How do I make a user info page like this:

[image]

For the grey background under the user icon, is it a widget? like simply user a image view or is there a better way to implement this?

And if I want the user icon to be a circle shape, other than customize a widget, is there a more convenient way to do it?

Comment: https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of circular ImageView for Android. It can be used with all kinds of drawables, i.e. a PicassoDrawable from Picasso or other non-standard drawables. Here is the link of library:
https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this class as your widget and set image inside same as imageview with picasso or image loader


public class CircularImageView extends ImageView
    {
    // Border & Selector configuration variables
    private boolean hasBorder;
    private boolean hasSelector;
    private boolean isSelected;
    private int borderWidth;
    private int canvasSize;
    private int selectorStrokeWidth;

// Objects used for the actual drawing
private BitmapShader shader;
private Bitmap image;
private Paint paint;
private Paint paintBorder;
private Paint paintSelectorBorder;
private ColorFilter selectorFilter;

public CircularImageView(Context context)
{
    this(context, null);
}

public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.circularImageViewStyle);
}

public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

/**
 * Initializes paint objects and sets desired attributes.
 * 
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 * @param defStyle
 */
private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    // Initialize paint objects
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paintBorder = new Paint();
    paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
    paintSelectorBorder = new Paint();
    paintSelectorBorder.setAntiAlias(true);

    // load the styled attributes and set their properties
    TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircularImageView, defStyle, 0);

    // Check if border and/or border is enabled
    hasBorder = attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircularImageView_border, false);
    hasSelector = attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircularImageView_selector, false);

    // Set border properties if enabled
    if(hasBorder) {
        int defaultBorderSize = (int) (2 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
        setBorderWidth(attributes.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.styleable.CircularImageView_border_width, defaultBorderSize));
        setBorderColor(attributes.getColor(R.styleable.CircularImageView_border_color, Color.WHITE));
    }

    // Set selector properties if enabled
    if(hasSelector) {
        int defaultSelectorSize = (int) (2 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
        setSelectorColor(attributes.getColor(R.styleable.CircularImageView_selector_color, Color.TRANSPARENT));
        setSelectorStrokeWidth(attributes.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.styleable.CircularImageView_selector_stroke_width, defaultSelectorSize));
        setSelectorStrokeColor(attributes.getColor(R.styleable.CircularImageView_selector_stroke_color, Color.BLUE));
    }

    // Add shadow if enabled
    if(attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircularImageView_shadow, false))
        addShadow();

    // We no longer need our attributes TypedArray, give it back to cache
    attributes.recycle();
}

/**
 * Sets the CircularImageView's border width in pixels.
 * 
 * @param borderWidth
 */
public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth)
{
    this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    this.requestLayout();
    this.invalidate();
}

/**
 * Sets the CircularImageView's basic border color.
 * 
 * @param borderColor
 */
public void setBorderColor(int borderColor)
{
    if (paintBorder != null)
        paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);
    this.invalidate();
}

/**
 * Sets the color of the selector to be draw over the 
 * CircularImageView. Be sure to provide some opacity.
 * 
 * @param selectorColor
 */
public void setSelectorColor(int selectorColor)
{
    this.selectorFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(selectorColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    this.invalidate();
}

/**
 * Sets the stroke width to be drawn around the CircularImageView 
 * during click events when the selector is enabled.
 * 
 * @param selectorStrokeWidth
 */
public void setSelectorStrokeWidth(int selectorStrokeWidth)
{
    this.selectorStrokeWidth = selectorStrokeWidth;
    this.requestLayout();
    this.invalidate();
}

/**
 * Sets the stroke color to be drawn around the CircularImageView 
 * during click events when the selector is enabled.
 * 
 * @param borderColor
 */
public void setSelectorStrokeColor(int selectorStrokeColor)
{
    if (paintSelectorBorder != null)
        paintSelectorBorder.setColor(selectorStrokeColor);
    this.invalidate();
}

/**
 * Adds a dark shadow to this CircularImageView.
 */
public void addShadow()
{
    setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
    paintBorder.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
}


@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    // Don't draw anything without an image
    if(image == null)
        return;

    // Nothing to draw (Empty bounds)
    if(image.getHeight() == 0 || image.getWidth() == 0)
        return;

    // Compare canvas sizes
    int oldCanvasSize = canvasSize;

    canvasSize = canvas.getWidth();
    if(canvas.getHeight() < canvasSize)
        canvasSize = canvas.getHeight();

    // Reinitialize shader, if necessary
    if(oldCanvasSize != canvasSize)
        refreshBitmapShader();

    // Apply shader to paint
    paint.setShader(shader);

    // Keep track of selectorStroke/border width
    int outerWidth = 0;

    // Get the exact X/Y axis of the view
    int center = canvasSize / 2;


    if(hasSelector && isSelected) { // Draw the selector stroke & apply the selector filter, if applicable
        outerWidth = selectorStrokeWidth;
        center = (canvasSize - (outerWidth * 2)) / 2;

        paint.setColorFilter(selectorFilter);
        canvas.drawCircle(center + outerWidth, center + outerWidth, ((canvasSize - (outerWidth * 2)) / 2) + outerWidth - 4.0f, paintSelectorBorder);
    }
    else if(hasBorder) { // If no selector was drawn, draw a border and clear the filter instead... if enabled
        outerWidth = borderWidth;
        center = (canvasSize - (outerWidth * 2)) / 2;

        paint.setColorFilter(null);
        canvas.drawCircle(center + outerWidth, center + outerWidth, ((canvasSize - (outerWidth * 2)) / 2) + outerWidth - 4.0f, paintBorder);
    }
    else // Clear the color filter if no selector nor border were drawn
        paint.setColorFilter(null);

    // Draw the circular image itself
    canvas.drawCircle(center + outerWidth, center + outerWidth, ((canvasSize - (outerWidth * 2)) / 2) - 4.0f, paint);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    // Check for clickable state and do nothing if disabled
    if(!this.isClickable()) {
        this.isSelected = false;
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    // Set selected state based on Motion Event
    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            this.isSelected = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            this.isSelected = false;
            break;
    }

    // Redraw image and return super type
    this.invalidate();
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}

public void invalidate(Rect dirty) {
    super.invalidate(dirty);
    image = drawableToBitmap(getDrawable());
    if(shader != null || canvasSize > 0)
        refreshBitmapShader();
}

public void invalidate(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.invalidate(l, t, r, b);
    image = drawableToBitmap(getDrawable());
    if(shader != null || canvasSize > 0)
        refreshBitmapShader();
}

@Override
public void invalidate() {
    super.invalidate();
    image = drawableToBitmap(getDrawable());
    if(shader != null || canvasSize > 0)
        refreshBitmapShader();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private int measureWidth(int measureSpec)
{
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // The parent has determined an exact size for the child.
        result = specSize;
    }
    else if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        // The child can be as large as it wants up to the specified size.
        result = specSize;
    }
    else {
        // The parent has not imposed any constraint on the child.
        result = canvasSize;
    }

    return result;
}

private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight)
{
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // We were told how big to be
        result = specSize;
    } else if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        // The child can be as large as it wants up to the specified size.
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // Measure the text (beware: ascent is a negative number)
        result = canvasSize;
    }

    return (result + 2);
}

/**
 * Convert a drawable object into a Bitmap
 * 
 * @param drawable
 * @return
 */
public Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable)
{
    if (drawable == null) { // Don't do anything without a proper drawable
        return null;
    }
    else if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) { // Use the getBitmap() method instead if BitmapDrawable
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    // Create Bitmap object out of the drawable
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}

/**
 * Reinitializes the shader texture used to fill in 
 * the Circle upon drawing.
 */
public void refreshBitmapShader()
{
    shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, canvasSize, canvasSize, false), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
}

/**
 * Returns whether or not this view is currently 
 * in its selected state.
 */
public boolean isSelected()
{
    return this.isSelected;
}
}

for full example refer https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView/blob/master/circularimageview-eclipse/CircularImageView/src/com/pkmmte/circularimageview/CircularImageView.java
```